# C and AVR pow function to light LEDs

Tags: c, arduino, avr, pow

I'm writing code to make a set of five LEDs appear to "bounce" back and forth "Knight Rider" style. When writing to the PORTB register, I noticed that the way I have the LEDs plugged in, the different things would be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16. those would turn the appropriate LEDs. So I figured that looping through using the `pow` function to set the register to the value of 2 raised to the LED number (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). It doesn't work right though.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

void delay(uint16_t x);
//void buttons(int b1, int b2);

int led = 0;
int inc = 1;
unsigned int ledpow = 0;

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1<<PORTB0); //Set PORTB0 (pin 8) as an output
    DDRB |= (1<<PORTB1); //Set PORTB1 (pin 9) as an output
    DDRB |= (1<<PORTB2); //Set PORTB2 (pin 10) as an output
    DDRB |= (1<<PORTB3); //Set PORTB3 (pin 11) as an output
    DDRB |= (1<<PORTB4); //Set PORTB4 (pin 12) as an output
    DDRD &= ~(1<<PORTD3); //Set PORTD3 (pin 3) as an input
    DDRD &= ~(1<<PORTD4); //Set PORTD4 (pin 4) as an input
    PORTB = 0; //Disable Pull-up resistors for PORTB
    PORTD = 0; //Disable Pull-up resistors for PORTD

    while(1)
    {
        while((PIND & (1<<PORTD3)) != 0) {
            //Do nothing, just pause the program
        }

        ledpow = pow(2,led);
        PORTB = ledpow;

        led = led + inc;

        if ((led == 4) || (led==0)) {
            inc = -inc;
        }

        if((PIND & (1<<PORTD4)) != 0) {
            delay(50);
        }
        else {
            delay(100);
        }
    }
}

void delay(uint16_t x)
{
    uint16_t i,j;

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
            ;
    return;
}
```

Why is this not working right? I had it working with a switch/case statement. And I tested that the `pow` function works by doing `PORTB = pow(2,0);` and the other powers that the variable "led" would be. That worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Because the pow function returns a floating-point number which is not an exact representation of the value which it is supposed to represent (and also, math functions work using approximations). So maybe `pow(2, 3)` doesn't return 8 but 7.99856 or 8.0000261 etc. In the former case, you're screwed, since when you assign it to the port, it gets truncated to an integer (ports hold integers, right?) and loses its fractional part, forming 7 to light up all the 3 first LEDs.

For integer operations, the pow function is also an overdue, you're wasting your shot. I'm wondering why don't you use `PORTB = 1 << led;` whereas you do use it for setting other port states...

Also, your delay loop is horribly unportable. Diving into AVR-libc's docs, there are two delay loop functions which provide almost exact-time delays. You can see how to use them in my AVR utility library: http://github.com/H2CO3/libavrutil

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `pow()`. You can find information on [`pow()` at C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/).

However, essentially, there is no `pow()` signature for integers:

> ```
>      double pow (      double base,      double exponent );
> long double pow ( long double base, long double exponent );
>       float pow (       float base,       float exponent );
>      double pow (      double base,         int exponent );
> long double pow ( long double base,         int exponent );
> ```

That means that at run-time, it may not work, because it will round the result. It would need the floating point library (fully implemented in software on the AVR) - which is slow and takes up space.

`PORTB = pow(2,0);` may work because it is a `constexpr`, so can be evaluated at compile time.

Instead, try use the left shift operator, eg:

```
PORTB = 1 << led;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to avoid pow completely. Instead of manipulation the ports go for the digitalWrite function.

```
void setup() {
    for (uint8_t pin=0; pin<20; ++pin) {
        pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    }
}

void blink(const uint8_t pos) {
    digitalWrite(pos, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(pos, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    for (uint8_t pos=0; pos<19; ++pos) {
        blink(pos);
    }
    for (uint8_t pos=19; pos>0; --pos) {
        blink(pos);
    }
}
```

More sophisticated knight rider versions can be found in my blog [here](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/basic-effects/knight-rider/) and [here](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/removing-flicker/knight-rider-no-flicker/)